# Finding Paths in Directed Graph with Greedy Approach With At Least K Nodes and a Given Starting Node

Tags: perl, algorithm, unix, graph

I have a non-weighted DAG graph. What I want to do is to find 
all the paths in a greedy way and the path should contain at least K nodes,
and a given starting node.

Is there any existing algorithm/implmentation that does that?

For example I have the following graph:

```
my %graph =(36=>[31],31=>[30,22],30=>[20],22=>[20,8],20=>[1],8=>[5],5=>[2],2=>[1,20]);
```

[image]

So if I define K=5 and starting node 36, I hope to get:

```
{1,20,22,31,36}
{1,20,2,5,8,22,31,36}
{1,20,30,31,36}
{1,2,5,8,22,31,36}
```

Comment: I looks like the number of such paths can grow exponentially on the number of nodes. How would you deal with that?

Comment: @Leonid: I will do that with heuristic e.g. removing certain nodes with certain condition (domain specific).

Comment: Would backtracking not solve your problem? Faster approach I would look at is thinking about the problem in terms of dynamic programming, given the certain domain specific conditions that can be applied. Without those conditions doesn't look like there is anything better than backtracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not very dificult.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @stack = ();

my %graph = (36=>[31],31=>[30,22],30=>[20],22=>[20,8],
             20=>[1],8=>[5],5=>[2],2=>[1,20]);

# add begin to stack
push(@stack, { node => 36, way => [36] });

while (@stack > 0) {

    my $node = pop(@stack);

    # way
    my $way = $node->{way};

    # complete way
    if ($node->{node} == 1) {
        print Dumper($node->{way});
    }

    # add next nodes
    my $nextArr = $graph{$node->{node}};

    for my $nextNod (@$nextArr) {
        # add way
        my @tmpWay = @$way;
        push(@tmpWay, $nextNod);

        # add to stack
        push(@stack, { node => $nextNod, way => \@tmpWay });
    }
}
```

So you can test, if node the end node and save all path (ways) out.
You must optimase this script

## edit

Add endless save protection.

## edit 2

You don't need a endless protection. Add shift to pop, then you search more than one way to end note :)

Comment: Thanks I have problem with the output. This two lines of yours gave error message. "push(@stack, { node => 36, way => [36] })" and "while (@#stack > 0) {". Please advice.

Comment: The code works now. It was only pseudo code, but I fix it for you... I hope that I dosn't made your homework.